# Regex expression working except in dotNet

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match an expression of type

```
field:"value"
```

but not

```
field:value
```

I have written

```
([a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?"(.+)"\s*?
```

and this works excepts in dotNet

Is there any reason why this might be? Something I am missing?

**Edit -- I typed the question wrong (figures)**

I'm trying to match

```
field:value
```

but not

```
field:"value"
```

This is the regex I have

```
(?<field>[a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?(?<value>[^"].+[^"])\s*?
```

But that's not working, it matches even what's in quotes.

**Edit 2:**

Below is the code --
`SearchResources.StringRegexNotQuotedText` is `([a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?([^"]+)\s*?`
`stringQuery` is (`what:  "Hello_bob"`)

All relevant things are escaped....

```
Regex regexNotQuoted = new Regex(SearchResources.StringRegexNotQuotedText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matchesNotQuoted = regexNotQuoted.Matches(stringQuery);

 // It should go into this block if the value is not in quotes
 if (regexNotQuoted.IsMatch(stringQuery))
 {

 }
```

Comment: Can you show us what the code that is failing looks like? I'm inclined to think that you did not type the regular expression correctly, even though you think you did. You probably forgot to escape things...

Comment: I mean, the actual C# or VB or whatever code you're using.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "everywhere except .NET"? Where does this regular expression work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part: `[^"].+` means: *a character other than double quotes, followed by one or more characters*. This means you only match sequences of at least *two* characters that start with non-double-quotes. You probably want `[^"].*`, that is, sequences of at least *one* character, that isn't a double quote;

Now, to the issue at hand. You're getting a match, because of this part `\s*?([^"].+[^"])`. The `\s*?` part will match no spaces because it is non-greedy (that's what the question mark means here). Then the `[^"]` part will match a space, `.+` will match `"Hello_bo` and the last `[^"]` will match the final `b`. The rest of the line (`"`) will not be captured.

You need to stop using the non-greedy operators (that's almost never what you want), and to make sure you capture everything to the end of the line, using the end-of-line anchor: `$`.

So, this is what I recommend you use:

```
(?<field>[a-z]+)\s*:\s*(?<value>[^"].*[^"])\s*$
```

With this C# code:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<field>[a-z]+)\s*:\s*(?<value>[^""].*[^""])\s*$");
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to match one or more characters other than double-quotes or whitespace, so write it just like that:

```
[^"\s]+
```

The full regex would be:

```
(?<field>[a-z]+)\s*:\s*(?<value>[^"\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me. Here is the code I've used:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"([a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?""(.+)""\s*?", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```